# Oracle Weblogic Server

Tags: 7, installation

My doubts about drupal requirements are:
- Can run Drupal 7 on a Oracle WebLogic Server? How would the integration be?
- Can i use the Oracle driver for this porpuse?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use [Oracle Driver](https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle).

> This is a driver that allows Drupal to use an Oracle Database instead
>   of MySQL as the primary backend.

Refer to these links :

1. [Link 1](http://www.greenbirdmedia.com/blog/how-install-drupal-oracle)
2. [Link 2](http://internetdevels.com/blog/oracle-install)

I hope these links may definitely solve your query.